# Make a table without sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm playing with php code and I'm trying to make tables without a sql, but i have a problem it's not work correctly this is my form

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Daftar Paket
            </td>
            <td>
            <select name="harga_paket">
            <?php 
                $paket="SELECT Nama_Paket from paket_harga"; 
                $querypkt=mysql_query($paket) or die(mysql_error());
                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($querypkt)){
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $data['Nama_Paket']?>" id="menu"><?php echo $data['Nama_Paket'] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Jumlah Paket
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="jumlah" id="jumlah">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="tambah" value="tambah">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and this is my php code

```
<table border="2">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Paket
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Jumlah
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Harga
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total Harga
                    </th>
                </tr>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["tambah"])){

        $paket = $_POST['harga_paket'];
        $jumlah = $_POST['jumlah'];

        $sqlharga=mysql_query("select Harga_Paket from paket_harga where Nama_Paket='".$paket."' ") ;
        $data=mysql_fetch_array($sqlharga);
        $harga=$data['Harga_Paket'];
        $total_harga = $harga * $jumlah ;
        $value=array($paket,$jumlah,$harga,$total_harga);

    if(isset($value)){
        $jumlah=count($value);
        for($i=1; $i<=1;$i++){
            echo "<tr></tr>";
            $row[$i]=$value;
            for($j=0;$j<=$jumlah-1;$j++){
        ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $row[$i][$j]; 

                        ?>
                    </td>
        <?php 
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

can you help me playing guys.? all your answer will appreciated :)

Comment: Using mysql and want to make a table in nosql????

Comment: If you don't want Mysql Table you may use SQLite

Comment: why not save data in text files. back to the stone age!!

Comment: no just playing with an array

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this. Well, this do use sql. :))

https://datatables.net/

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables